# How to Change Access Permissions of a Running Task (c)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I want to change the permissions of a memory segment at run time (the memory section contains a function that I want to change its code at run time).

My first thought was to change the permissions to write - read, make the changes, return the permissions to execute only.

The thing is that I need to get the base address of my page, not the address of my function and only then I can tweak the permissions.

Here is the code, where I tried to execute it:

```
void encrypt_function()
{
    PBYTE start_addr = (PBYTE)&function_to_hide1; // get location of function (can get some time jmp stub instead of actual function - need to find better approach).
    DWORD size = (UINT_PTR)&empty_staub - (UINT_PTR)&function_to_hide1;


    // try to get the base address of my function page - failed  
    _MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION lpBuffer;
    VirtualQuery(start_addr, &lpBuffer, size);

    DWORD old_flags = 0;
    if (!VirtualProtect(start_addr, size, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &old_flags)) // ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS - it's not the base address
    {
        printf("went rung %d", GetLastError());
    }// make function page read write execute permission

    // can't be done - i dont have permission
    for (DWORD i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    {
        start_addr[i] ^= 0x55;
    }

    VirtualProtect(start_addr, size, old_flags, NULL);
}
```

For some reason, I cannot get the base address (the linker will not compile this code for some reason).

Does anyone know a better way to do this (modify permissions and perform function modification)?

Comment: A linker does not compile code. If you get a linker error, show that exact error. in your question. It's unclear, why you declare the `VirtualProtect` function.

Comment: `DWORD size = (UINT_PTR)&empty_staub - (UINT_PTR)&function_to_hide1` - even if you declare `empty_staub` immediately after `function_to_hide1` in code, there is no guarantee that the compiler/linker will place `empty_staub` immediately after `function_to_hide1` in the final executable

Comment: Don't do this. Use a detour.

Comment: @RemyLebeau i declere function_to_hide1 and empty_staub  with code_seg(".my_seg$1") so the linker will place the function 1 after the outher.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i didn't understand you, where to use detour?

Comment: Don't overwrite the code. Use a detour instead. Then you don't care how much space the original function takes up.

Comment: @YoramAbargel see [Modifying application behavior with Detours](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jannemattila/2009/12/03/modifying-application-behavior-with-detours-for-application-compatibility-reasons/)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i'm try to decrypt function at run time for better drm, i not sure i can use detours for this , my main point is to decrypt the function and in the rest of the time , make it consiled

Comment: Use VirtualAlloc. Decrypt to there. Then detour to it. Or don't bother with the detour and just call the function directly.

Answer (score 0):

To get the base address of the page in which your function resides you can use VirtualQuery(), then you pass mbi.BaseAddress to the VirtualProtect() call.

```cpp
MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;

VirtualQuery(start_addr, &mbi, sizeof(mbi));

DWORD oldprotect;
VirtualProtect(mbi.BaseAddress, mbi.RegionSize, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldprotect);
```

As was discussed in the comments you should use VirtualAlloc() to get a new memory space and decrypt your function there,and do a simple detour to jump to it rather than doing the decryption in place.